# Docker set ipaddress and start services

Tags: linux, networking, docker, dockerfile

I have setup docker and create container but problem is i want to bring up on my `LAN` IP subnet, I have configured `docker0` has bridged and start `docker -d -b docker0`, Now i want to start container with `static` IP and start `httpd` and `mysqld` services.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos/centos6-latest
RUN /sbin/ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.150
RUN /sbin/route add default gw 192.168.1.1
RUN /etc/init.d/mysqld start
RUN /etc/init.d/httpd start
```

Error:

```
[root@server ~]# docker build -t centos/centos6-latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 146.8 MB
Sending build context to Docker daemon
Step 0 : FROM centos/centos6-latest
 ---> 123729f9961b
Step 1 : RUN /sbin/ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.150
 ---> Running in c722910e1997
SIOCSIFADDR: Permission denied
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Permission denied
SIOCSIFNETMASK: Permission denied
SIOCSIFBROADCAST: Permission denied
2014/12/23 07:03:38 The command [/bin/sh -c /sbin/ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.150] returned a non-zero code: 255
```

I know you have to start container with `--privileged` mode but i don't know how do i set it with `build` option

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers are not full virtual machines.

Network configuration is done at boot, not build.   You cannot assign a static ip without an external tool like [pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework).  I would suggest reading the [networking docs](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/).   A static IP is not 'the docker way'.

Also, containers do not typically use a full blown init system.   If you must start multiple services, [supervisord](https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/) or [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) are common alternatives.

The privileged flag is specified at docker run, not during the build process.